# Is there any helper functions to build forms in CKAN?

Tags: ckan

I have to create a multipage form and was wondering if I can just follow Pylons documentation on helper functions to build forms in CKAN?

Is there any documentation in CKAN for creating forms? Please suggest the best approach.

Comment: Please include some code so your peers can see what you have tried. You can't expect the SO community to do it all for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CKAN forms usually import some macros located in ckan/templates/macros. Have a look at form.html and you'll get the idea. Also have a look at one of the examples (ckanext/example_idatasetform).

Basically you'd import the macros with `{% import 'macros/form.html' as form %}` and then build the form with those macros, like this:

```
{% block package_basic_fields_custom %}
{{ form.input('custom_text', label=_('Custom Text'), 
id='field-custom_text', placeholder=_('custom text'), 
value=data.custom_text, error=errors.custom_text, classes= ['control-medium']) }}
{% endblock %}
```

AFAIK there's no special documention on how to create forms in CKAN. You should have a look at the relevant templates in ckan/templates/package

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hope I will be able to dig into the pointers you have provided to learn how forms are created in CKAN.

Comment: I was able to create a simple form using the form macros in CKAN. However, I have not been able to validate form fields and setting field error message. Where should I create form field validation rule? I assume the "errors" is a dict object that I have to populate prior to the start of the form code.

Comment: CKAN provides some basic validators, that you can use with the plugin toolkit. Have a look at the above mentioned ckanext/example_idatasetform how to do that in plugin.py. The validator functions are in ckan/lib/navl/validators.py. Writing your own validations should be possible, but I've never done that, yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have not been able to figure out the "data" and "errors" in code like the following: {{ form.input('title', label=_('Title'), value=data.title, error=errors.title) }}. Are these some global objects/dictionary? I am not sure how to create or set attributes of these two objects.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind upvoting the answers and comments? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is documentation for the built-in form element macros for CKAN 2.6.0a in the comments of `/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/macros/form.html`, and also in the [Frontend Development Guidelines, under Templating](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.3.3/contributing/frontend/templating.html#form-macros).

Note that the documentation tells you to add the line:

> `{% import 'macros/form.html' as form %}`

but if you're overriding an existing template (using `{% ckan_extends %}`) you don't typically have to add this import line because that is usually already in place, or already included in a parent template.